# draw inclined plane

Tags: tikz-pgf, physics

I am trying to draw this thing:

[image]

here's what I have done so far (my pic is slightly different, but it is okay for my purposes)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
            
    \coordinate (a) at (3.5,0.35);
    \coordinate (b) at (3.5,1.75);
    \coordinate (c) at (2.95,1.5);
            
    \draw[line width=0.6mm] (0,0) -- (8,0) -- (8,4) -- cycle;
    \draw[line width=0.6mm,-stealth,blue,rotate=26.57] (-1,0) -- (10,0);
    \draw[line width=0.6mm,black,rotate=26.57,fill=lightgray] (3.1305,0.05) rectangle (5.1305,1.05);
            
    \draw[line width=0.6mm,-stealth, red] (3.5,2.35) -- (3.5,0.35);
    \draw[line width=0.6mm,-stealth, red,rotate=26.57] (4.2,0.55) -- (5.7,0.55);
    \draw[line width=0.6mm,-stealth, blue,rotate=26.57] (4.2,0.55) -- (3.3,0.55);
    \draw[line width=0.3mm,dashed, blue,rotate=26.57] (3.3,0.55) -- (3.3,-1);
    \draw[line width=0.6mm,-stealth, red,rotate=26.57] (4.2,0.55) -- (4.2,2.05);
            
    \node[circ,red] at (3.5,2.35){};
            
    \draw[line width=0.3mm] (1,0) arc (0:26.57:1);
            
    \pic [draw, -, line width = 0.3mm, angle eccentricity=1.5,green] {angle = b--a--c};
    \pic [draw, -, line width = 0.3mm, angle eccentricity=1.5,green] {angle = c--b--a};
            
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which gives me this:
[image]

So I have a few questions:

1. Is there any way to change the radius of these arcs that show angles? For some reason one green angle is okay, but the other is too big. It also made me to draw the main `\alpha` angle as an arc
2. In case there's no way to change this arc radius, how can I draw my picture normally?

I know the code is awful :\

Comment: The key [`angle radius`](https://tikz.dev/library-angle#tikz/angle:radius) ought to be able to help with the, well, angle radius.

Comment: oh, that was obvious, thank you!